# Depth Layers in android

Tags: android, android-animation, parallax

I would like to achieve something like this video:
https://youtu.be/i-akLH91U0Y
multiple images layered on top of each other, that get distorted (upon swipe/accelerometer) with different ratios and angles, giving the impression that you are looking at a 3D model from different angles.
Any idea would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using a game engine? Unity game engine has a lot of the features you are looking for. Look at this example I came across that uses parallax scrolling for 2d image backgrounds.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkisHNmcK7Y

Comment: I've already thought of that, but it seems like using too much resource for such a simple task.
I already have an idea in mind, which is to create a simple function that distorts an array of views (giving them perspective) where the input value is the amount of swipe (right/left/up/down)